# Expressing spherical harmonics as a combination of other spherical harmonics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, special-functions, mathematical-physics, spherical-harmonics

Spherical harmonics are a useful tool in physics, particularly in classic electrostatics and electrodynamics. Given an integer $l$, the spherical harmonic $Y_{l,m}$, where $-l\leq m\leq l$, solves the PDE
$$
\nabla^2Y_{l,m} + \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}Y_{l,m} = 0
$$
Given $l$, there are $2l+1$ solutions to the above equation. These solutions are linearly independent (as the $Y_{l,m}$ form a complete set of orthonormal functions), but the degree of the equation is only 2, so there suppose to be only 2 linearly independent solutions that span the solution space. How is this not a contradiction?

Comment: The rule about the dimension of the solution space equalling the degree only applies to ODEs.

Comment: So what is the situation in PDEs?

Comment: There's no hard-and-fast rule: for example, the wave equation $u_{tt}-c^2 u_{xx}=$ in $1+1$ dimensions is solved by any sufficiently smooth function of the form $f(x \pm ct)$. Laplace's equation in two dimensions is solved by any function of the form $ f(x+iy) + g(x-iy) $, and so on.

Comment: What you're talking about is *polynomial* solutions to the three-dimensional Laplace equation: any homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ that solves Laplace's equation is a solution to the equation $\nabla^2 p =0 $, and homogeneity allows one to write this as $ \nabla^2(r^n f(\theta,\phi))=0 $, and expanding this gives your equation. http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/m435f07/m435sphericalharmonics.pdf gives a nice rundown of where the dimension comes from.